# How to resolve "empty links" for ADA compliance?

Tags: accessibility, wcag

We are among a group of realtor companies in our area that have been targeted and told we'll be sued for not having ADA compliant site. We are going to make our site compliant as one of the ways to fight it.

One of the things mentioned was "empty links" on the homepage. Does anyone know how to resolve these? Would it just be an image without an alt tag?

Comment: Go to my stackoverflow profile page and you'll see a LinkedIn URL to me.  I helped a realtor last month with this exact same issue.  You most likely got a report with the semi-fake ADA complaint from the lawyer.  That report will have more details of what they are supposedly complaining about. There's more to it than that so a conversation is need.  For this particular issue, if you have a link that has an image embedded in it, and the image is the only thing inside the link **and** the image doesn't have an `alt` attribute, that would cause an "empty link" error.

Comment: It's pretty easy to fix, but again, there's a lot more to this than the one error.  In the meantime, you can add `aria-label` to your `<a>` or you can add `alt` to your `<img>`.

Answer (score 0):

Download Mozilla Firefox. Install the AInspector plugin. Navigate to your webpage. Open up Ainspector. It will show all of your violations/errors/etc and how to fix them.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ainspector-wcag/

[image]